# Remove whitespace elements in list (scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

I have a list of several elements, some of which are useful and have text, some of which are "" (empty / null), and some of which are various whitespaces ("  ","      "," ").

Is there a built-in function to check whether the whole element is a whitespace?
Just to be clear, I do not want ("foo foo1 foo2") to become ("foofoo1foo2").

Thanks

edit: when I tried to implement Justin Ethier's solution, I got this error.
ERROR: wrong type to apply: ""

the code i ran was

```
;;;Predicate for checking if a string is not empty or full of whitespaces
(define (notwhitespace? str)
  (if (equal? str "") #F 
    (call-with-current-continuation
     (lambda (return)
      (for-each
       (lambda (c)
         (if (not (char-whitespace? c)) #T #F))
        (string->list str))
        #F)
      )
    )
)
```

i used this in conjunction with a filter to try to remove the elements from the list.

```
 (define (notwhitespace? str)
  (if (equal? str "") (return #f)
  (every char-whitespace? (string->list str))
  )
)
```

I'm using MIT scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in function `char-whitespace?` that you can use to determine if a single character is whitespace or not. You could then wrap it in a function to test a whole string, eg:

```
(call/cc
  (lambda (return)
    (for-each
      (lambda (c)
        (if (not (char-whitespace? c)) (return #t) #f))
      (string->list "  ")) ; Substitute your string var here
    #f))
```

Or more succinctly:

```
(every char-whitespace? (string->list my-string))
```

You can create a function based on this, and then use it together with `filter` to remove any such strings from your list.

Comment: It is much better to use `andmap` or the like instead of an imperative loop. IMHO.

Comment: hi, i tried implementing your explanation, but got an error (wrong type to apply: ""). I put my code up in the original question. Could you please let me know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need a special case to handle the empty string `""`, instead of calling `for-each`. Alternatively you could use the example with `every`.

Comment: hm, your comment implies that using the example with 'every' means that a special case to handle the empty string isn't necessary. I just tried using every, but I still got the same error. is the special case still needed?

Comment: It works for me. What code are you using that causes the error, and what Scheme are you using?

Comment: `return` is not a keyword, you just want to say `#f`.

Comment: I feel like my filter implementation is wrong now, because I'm getting "Wrong type to apply: #f". i'm using (updated-list (filter nonwhitespace? strlist))

Comment: alright, turns out too many parentheses caused that issue. However, The list actually returns empty, which means there might be something wrong with the predicate?

Comment: If this person is learning Scheme I wouldn't take out `call/cc` nor `for-each` of my hat. SRFI-1's `every`, SFRI-13's `string-index` or plain iteration with named `let` are better options.

Answer (score -4):

There's no built-in function in any language that I know of that will clean your objects the way you are suggesting. You can pass your list object to another method/function of the same type that will do the trick. Some code sample may be helpful in giving more specific answer but here is a logic that might help clean your list object:

```
function ListObject functionName(ListObject yourListObject)
{
    ListObject newListObject = new ListObject();
    foreach(var item in yourListObject)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        {
            newListObject.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return newListObject;
}
```

Comment: This question is about Scheme, not C#. I understand that your answer is language-agnostic but the correct solution approach for Scheme is nothing like the C# snippet you posted.

Comment: My answer was more directed to the way the problem should be approached logically as oppose to what solution to use. Maybe not the right answer but not the right logic? Doubt it.

Comment: Indeed, even the logic is totally different. C# is not a functional programming language, and the solution approach to this differs when using a functional language.